# istartsurf on chomium

Tags: security, chromium, malware

A few days ago I noticed that I'd got the istartsurf malware in Chromium on my Ubuntu laptop despite being careful of which software I'm installing, but anyway. So I reinstalled Ubuntu on my laptop and installed Chromium, FreeCAD, Blender, Gimp, Inkscape, Gnumeric and Homebank through the Ubuntu software-center and everything was fine. I surfed the web in yesterday evening and everything was fine.

Today when I get back on the laptop (it had been in sleepmode during the night with a few tabs open i chromium) I open up another chromium window, and there it was; istartsurf. It doesn't appear to have affected firefox since I can open a new window in firefox without having istartsurf as a hompage. I will however reinstall ubuntu on my laptop again but my question is; Have anyone encountered this problem before and does anyone know how I could have gotten the malware? I haven't installed anything except what's mentioned above and all had been through the software-center which makes me think that one (or more) of the programs within the software-center is infected (is it possible?). I use most of the programs on a rather regular basis so I'm inclined to install them again when I've reinstalled Ubuntu although I'd prefer to avoid getting the malware again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the web, it seems that istartsurf is a Windows malware. I'd suggest hardening your Windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good guide that could help you to clean your laptop from istartsurf virus http://removalbits.com/removal-of-istartsurf-com-virus-from-internet-explorer-firefox-and-google-chrome/. Just follow it step by step and you will not need to reinstall your OS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.